Dificulty navigating pandas documentation
I wanted to draw a boxplot that did not stop at IQR*1.5, but instead went all the way, without classification of outliers
Chatgpt, it turns out, knows the answer
ax = df_heights['height'].plot.box(sym='')
However, I cannot find documentation for this sym argument!
I went to
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.box.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot.box
and then looked for 'additional keywords' in
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot
as instructed. But I could not find the parameter there.
What am I missing?

the last line of the second link in the pandas documentation comments that there are even more kwargs, and those are passed to matplotlib itself!
so I guessed a google query and found the answer
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html
